# startProbability in hidden markov models

Tags: nlp, tagging, text-mining, hidden-markov-models, pos-tagger

How can I calculate the startProbabilitise in hidden markov model for POS tagging? is that means: (# repeats of one tag)/(# repeats of all tags)? or (number of sentences beginning with one tag)/(all sentences)? if not, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering a second order HMM, Maximum Likelihood Estimate gives:

```
P(SomeTag | <BOS>,<BOS>) = count(<BOS>,<BOS>,SomeTag) / count(<BOS>,<BOS>)
```

It corresponds to your second proposal:

> (number of sentences beginning with one tag)/(all sentences)